# Can you disable the lasers in Framing Frame day 1?

Tags: payday-2

The lasers in the doorway are disabled when a guard walks nearby. Can I kill a guard near the doorway so the lasers stay disabled? Are there other ways to disable the lasers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot disable the lasers without getting an alarm. Getting an alarm is the only way to disable the lasers, and that defeats the whole purpose of disabling them. The lasers go back on shortly after being disabled even if the guard dies within range.

[image: guard right at the doorway with lasers]